# Dragging and reordering listbox items in Windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8, drag-and-drop, listbox

I have been looking for a drag and drop listbox, but I guess there is no such default control. A bit of searching has given me,[Jason's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jasongin/archive/2011/04/13/pull-down-to-refresh-a-wp7-listbox-or-scrollviewer.aspx?CommentPosted=true#commentmessage) in which he has pulled it off very gracefully.. In the code he has written, there is a the drag and drop handler which is present at the right end of every listboxitem.. You press on the handler and move the item up or down. I am trying to implement the same on the long press of the item..

He uses a drag interceptor which is basically a canvas and it sits on top of listbox to capture the listboxitem manipulation events. If I want the same manipulation on the hold event of the listbox item, how do I trigger it??

This is how I have linked the events to the drag interceptor.
How do i call the Manipulation Started on the hold of the listbox item?? Or is there some other way to do this?

```
this.dragInterceptor.ManipulationStarted += this.dragInterceptor_ManipulationStarted;
this.dragInterceptor.ManipulationDelta += this.dragInterceptor_ManipulationDelta;
this.dragInterceptor.ManipulationCompleted += this.dragInterceptor_ManipulationCompleted;
this.dragInterceptor.Hold += dragInterceptor_Hold;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried only adding the manipulation event handlers once the hold event is triggered? Or adding a flag which is set on `Hold` and cleared on `ManipulationCompleted` to test if the hold was done before running the main code in the other manipulation events.

Comment: I have tried adding the manipulationevent only after the hold is triggered.. and it does not work :( And about setting the a bool, the problem is, ManipulationStarted gets called before the hold event.. So the bool check becomes invalid :(

Comment: As Hold is at a higher level than the manipulation events, it looks then like you'll need to use a timer and detect the hold yourself based on the timer (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846816/how-to-implement-long-press-using-manipulation-events-in-windows-phone-8/18851980?noredirect=1#comment27815203_18851980) rather than using the event.

Answer (score 1):

I triggered the manipulation events of the reorder listbox by sending the arguments (object sender and ManipulationStartedEventArgs) from the mainpage.xaml.