# How to implement long press using manipulation events in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, swipe, listboxitem, long-press

Since `GestureListener` is deprecated, we are now left with three events namely `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationDelta`, `ManipulationCompleted`.

My custom listbox enables, swiping left and right on listbox items to do certain functions. How do I use the manipulation events to detect long press on a listboxitem? I want to implement the long press in such a way that the swipe left and right is not broken.

Any clue/idea would be of great help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Phone 8 includes a `Hold` event. Can you sue that for detecting the long press?

If not, you'll need to use a timer within your manipulation events to determine the length of time between starting a manipulation and whether the point of manipulation moves (triggering a delta event) and so suggesting a swipe gesture OR if a delta or completed event is not fired within your defined amount of time then you can assume a long press.

Comment: So what happens is ManipulationEventStarted gets called first, then followed by Hold event..

Comment: If you're using a timer and the manipulation events, don't use the Hold event too. X-REF http://stackoverflow.com/q/18828530/1755